# jQuery select div with specific style for removal

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to locate a div and remove it, currently i have...

```
jQuery('.disable_label').next().remove();
```

My problem is that I have several divs with a class of disable_label.  How can I modify this snippet to only select the disable_label divs that have display:none set?

UPDATE

I am now using this..

```
jQuery('.disable_label:visible').next().remove();
```

To try and select all instances of .disable_label that have a css value of display:list-item but it's not working.

Can I target display:list-item itself?

Comment: [`.disable_label:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Comment: Jared is right, `$('.disable_label:hidden')` will work.

Answer (score 2):

[`.disable_label:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

From the jQuery `:hidden` documentation:

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> - They have a CSS `display` value of `none`.
> - They are form elements with `type="hidden"`.
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> - An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.
>
> Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout. During animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end of the animation.

Comment: How about the opposite of this?  What if I wanted to select all of the instances that did not has display:none?

Comment: Thanks, can i select all css elements like that? Like if I wanted to select all instances that have display:list-item?

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem. As the documentation mentions above, it's actually selecting for elements that have layout.

Comment: It is not working for me for some reason, I have updated the original question

Comment: It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/47EEm/ You will need to show your HTML and preferably a working fiddle showing the problem.